# Azure VM network bandwith

Tags: azure, file-transfer, azure-virtual-machine, bandwidth

We are currently configuring an Azure VM (Standard B4ms (4 vcpus, 16 GB memory))

This runs a .Net  WCF service for transfering files to our Windows Application client. (It's a quite specialized service and cannot easily be replaced by a Azure Storage Rest API, that's why we are going for this solution for now)

This works but I have found out that the file **transfer is painfully slow** (3 times slower than on our old server setup).

Therefore I made some simple tests on the VM showing the network throughput while transferring  a large file.

It seems like the network connection going to the client (Internet) is somehow limited to **21 Mb/s**.

It's excactly the same service that's runs on our other setup at a *substantially* faster speed.

Tried to make a file copy through RDP, and the situation was the same, it maxed out on 21 Mb/s.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? It seems like a very slow connection, and it doesn't seem to be incidental.

I tried to upsize the VM to a F8s, but that didn't do anything. Then to a Standard DS3_v2. Still the same.

I have been going through all network related resources and the VM in the Azure admin but I cannot find anything that seems related to network bandwidth.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read through the documentation for different sizes of VM and thought I found the reason in the B series not having enough network bandwidth. So I up-sized to a Standard DS3_v2, but the result is stille exactly the same: Max 21Mbs

Comment: This is developing in another direction than we thought. We are right now struggling to find the reason behind a large amount of packet fragmentation on TLS1.2 packages at our network supplier.

Comment: Did you ever find a cause for this? I have an Azure VM uploading something to the internet but the speed is constantly around 21 mbps.